# Conectar banco de dados class

Tags: php

Como faço para não precisar conectar no banco de dados a cada function em class PHP?

estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
class Perguntas {
    public function __construct(){
       $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','game');
    }
    public function exemplo(){
       $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM perguntas");
       $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
       echo ....;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem que fazer uma classe que tenha a responsabilidade de se conectar ao banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<?php

class Perguntas {
//Deixando a variável $mysli publica, ela pode ser acessada por qualquer um, 
//caso queira que ela seja acessada apenas na class, você pode deixa-lá como 
//private.

public $mysqli;

    public function __construct(){
        //p: serve para usar uma conexão existente caso essa já tenha sido 
        //criada, assim evita de ficar usando memoria do servidor atoa

       $this->mysqli = new mysqli('p:localhost','root','','game');
       //$this->nome_da_viável faz com que você acesse a variável fora da 
       //função, como ela está fora, qualquer outra função pode acessa-la 
       //também, como você já a definiu como contendo os dados com banco é 
       //só utiliza-lá como fiz na função abaixo.

       return true;
    }

    public function exemplo(){
       $resultado = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM perguntas");
       $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
       return $row;
    }
}


$perguntas = new perguntas();

var_dump($perguntas->exemplo());
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma classe de conexão com método estático. Assim o atributo `$mysql` será configurado apenas uma vez e poderá ser usado por outras classes.

Classe **`Conexao.php`**

```
class Conexao{

    public static $mysql;

    function __construct(){
        $this::setSql();
    }

    static function setSql(){
        self::$mysql= new mysqli('p:localhost','root','','game');
    }

}
```

Classe **`Perguntas.php`**

```
class Perguntas{

    public function exemplo(){
       $mysqli = Conexao::$mysql;
       $selecao = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM perguntas");
       print_r($selecao);
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include("Conexao.php");
include("Perguntas.php");
new Conexao();
$perguntas = new Perguntas();
$perguntas -> exemplo();
```

O atributo criado está publico, porém se você altera-lo de `public static $mysql;` para `protected static $mysql;` apenas as classes que são extendidas a classe Conexão que poderão acessar esse atributo.

Assim:

```
class Perguntas extends Conexao{

    public function exemplo(){
       $mysqli = Conexao::$mysql;
       $selecao = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM perguntas");
       print_r($selecao);
    }
}
```